# How can I pass an attribute from one component to another in EmberJS?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-data, ember.js-component

I have a component that has anchor tag click that opens a modal and within the model is a youtube . When the modal opens I want the id in the Youtube url to change in order to play the correct video, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to get this done. I added data-attributes with the id I need and was looking to pass this into the component to have it added to the url. I was thinking I could update an id in the component JS file.

src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/***{{id}}***?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0"

Below is the Handlebars templating and JS.

```
{{#bs-modal-simple open=modal1 title="Simple Dialog" size="lg" position="center" onHidden=(action (mut modal1) false)}}
  {{yt-ad-videos}}
{{/bs-modal-simple}}
```

JS:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
export default Component.extend({
  click(evt){
    let ytId = evt.target.getAttribute('data-id');
    this.set('id', ytId);
  },
  id: null,
  actions: {
    openModal() {
      this.get('onOpen')();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

um, where do you get the data from? This code does not make much sense:

```
click(evt){
  let ytId = evt.target.getAttribute('data-id');
  this.set('id', ytId);
},
```

where do you set the `data-id`?

Usually you would call your component like this:

```
{{my-component videoId="TheId"}}
```

or an example with dynamic data:

```
{{my-component videoId=model.youtubeId}}
```

Then inside `my-component.hbs` you can wrap it in a modal and use the `videoId`. You can directly pass the `videoId` to another component.

```
<button onclick={{action (mut modal1) true}}>Open</button>
{{#bs-modal-simple
  open=modal1
  title="Simple Dialog"
  size="lg"
  position="center"
  onHidden=(action (mut modal1) false)
}}
  {{ember-youtube ytid=videoId}}
{{/bs-modal-simple}}
```

Here I've used the [ember-youtube](https://github.com/oskarrough/ember-youtube) component because I dont know how your `yt-ad-videos` is implemented. You need to look inside it to figure out how to pass the id.

---

Sidenote: I recommend you to not use the `click()` event on the component tag. Use a closure action instead, like I did with the `<button>` to open the modal.

Comment: I have the ids hard coded on the anchor tags and the modal is from ember-bootstrap. data-attribute="video  is here" in one component and then adding the YouTube iFrame to the modal via another component. Is there a better approach to how I have it setup?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by *anchor tags*? you seems to not really understand the component concept. Maybe also check out the ember community #help slack channel for a discussion.

Comment: A standard anchor tag. <a href="">text</a> I'm using it to open the modal. When you click the text the modal opens. I have the modal opening, but I need to pass that specific ID, to play that specific video. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not really. can you provide an [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/)?

Comment: I'm using https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/#/components/modal but instead of opening it via a button I'm opening the modal via an anchor tag element. I'm adding my YouTube iFrame into the modal. I created the YouTube iFrame as it's own component and when the modal opens a different video needs to play depending on which element was clicked. i.e <a href="#" data-id="some video id" >play video one</a> or <a href="#" data-id="some video id" >play video two</a>, etc... What I want to do is update the id in the YouTube URL to play the appropriate video.

Comment: dont do this. you should do it the ember way. try to provide a minimal twiddle and I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://ember-twiddle.com/eed3b6dfa2ddcffac0677e29afe83aba?openFiles=templates.components.my-component.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.my-component.hbs). (Its not working because of the twiddle sandbox, however it should work like this in a real project)

Comment: Just started learning Ember and working on a small project to get familiar. I was working from the index file so I had to add a controller. Adding a controller resolved my issue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a controller for the index allowed me to pass the data I needed and resolved my issue.